# PHP 1 is displayed instead of an image

Tags: php, typo3

```
public function main($content, array $conf) {
    $this->conf = $conf;
    $this->pi_setPiVarDefaults();
    $this->pi_loadLL();


    $content = '';

    $background_image = $this->cObj->parentRecord['data']['media'];

    // Wenn ein Bild vorhanden ist
    if ($background_image != '') {
        $content .= '<img src="uploads/media/'.$background_image.'" alt="" title="" width="100%" />';
    }

    return $this->pi_wrapInBaseClass($content);
}
```

When expecting html I'm getting path like this:

```
<img src="uploads/media/1" alt="" title="" width="100%">
```

This is not written by me so that's why it's to understand why it behaves the way it does. Appreciate any tips.

Comment: `print_r($background_image)`

Comment: Getting 1 printed which makes me think the problem is in:
$background_image = $this->cObj->parentRecord['data']['media'];

Comment: Which TYPO3 version?

Comment: Und "Wenn ***K***ein Bild vorhanden ist"?  (When there is no image?) Even your `alt=""` is empty, and there is no `else` to the `if` - is that really what you want?

Comment: It's Typo3 7.6.21

Answer (score 1):

`['data']['media']` is a field used by FAL. The field itself only contains the number of references.

You need to resolve these reference with the FAL API, you may take a look [here](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/FileAbstractionLayerReference/UsingFal/Examples/FileFolder/Index.html#getting-referenced-files)